# Any emacs add-in for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, add-in

I know about the included emacs keybindings, it's barely ok.

I want to know if there exists a more thorough emacs add-in for visual studio similar to [viemu for vi](http://www.viemu.com/).

I found [VisEmacs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/visemacs/) but it seems unfinished.

Comment: It's more likely that you'll get the results you want going in the other direction; adding stuff to Emacs until it's more like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [XKeymacs](http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html), which sets up emacs key bindings in any windows application.  I tried and abandoned it, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this by hooking the application's message loop and "eating" all keystrokes. When a key sequence to perform some action is entered, send Visual Studio a direct editing command for processing.

I've done this with the mouse so I could turn mouse wheel into pageup/down instead of zoom.

I'd need to see the emacs commands state machine to give more specifics.

Edit: You'd have to track the editor focus to know what is active (dialog, tool pane, text editor, designer, properties window, etc.), but that's not bad once you've done it a few times.

Edit 2: My add-in mentioned above is open source (GPL) so you can see if it gives you a starting place. You can either install it and find the source in the Program Files directory, or use 7-zip to decompress the installer to pull the source's .7z file out without installing. [Here's a link (SamTools Releases).](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Releases)

Comment: Let me know if you have questions. I'd be interested to see this work out even though I'd *never* use it. Advanced key binding state flow in complex applications is a challenging and entertaining problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 released a nice add-in that makes coding in Visual Studio *almost* the same as emacs. I found this to be the best solution.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92/view/Discussions